# SQL Server, horizontal concatenate Range of Dates

Tags: sql, date, concatenation

I would like to know the way I could concatenate between two dates in a calculated column horizontally, for example:

```
date_ini,date_end,result
2016-04-01,2016-04-05,2016-04-01|2016-04-02|2016-04-03|2016-04-04|2016-04-05
2016-04-03,2016-04-06,2016-04-03|2016-04-04|2016-04-05|2016-04-06
2016-04-05,2016-04-05,2016-04-05
2016-04-05,2016-04-06,2016-04-05|2016-04-06
```

The result is the column I would like to create

Thanks,

Comment: Please provide your source data and expected output (in a clear format). Table structures are also often helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are all of those dates supposed to be your desired output or is that poorly-formatted sample data?

Comment: Creating a delimited list is usually a task for the client.

Comment: Hi,the source data is only the column date_ini and date_end
with this 2 dates, i would like to get de Result Column
with the list of dates between the date_ini and date_end

Answer (score 0):

A function like this could do the trick. Please change the size of the return varchar to fit your needs.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.date_concatenate(@start_date DATETIME, @end_date DATETIME)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @result VARCHAR(255);
  SET @result = '';
  IF(@end_date < @start_date)
    SET @result = 'Error: End Date can not be less than start date';
  ELSE
    BEGIN
      WHILE (@start_date < @end_date)
        BEGIN
          SET @result = @result + CONVERT(varchar(10),@start_date,120) + '|'
          SET @start_date = DATEADD(dd,1,@start_date)
        END
    END
  SET @result = @result + CONVERT(varchar(10),@end_date,120)
  RETURN @result
END
```

Comment: It doesn´t work beacuse of : Cannot assign a default value to a local variable

Comment: Did you created the function and then called it with legit arguments. Try this:    USE {database_name};
SELECT dbo.date_concatenate('2016-04-01', '2016-04-05')                              I did exactly this and got this: 2016-04-01|2016-04-02|2016-04-03|2016-04-04|2016-04-05

Comment: I forget to mention i'm sql server 2005

Comment: Updated the function code above, please try running it now. Should work. Once the function is created, try calling it as I did in my above mentioned comment.

Comment: 'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name
Column, parameter, or variable #1: Cannot find data type DATE.

Comment: updated the function above..can you check if it works..I dont have sql server 2005 environment so i cant check.